# Let $A$ be a square matrix with complex entries, and let $A^*$ denote the conjugate transpose of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a square matrix with complex entries, and let $A^*$ denote the conjugate transpose of $A$. Show that $AA^*=A^*A$ if and only if rank $(A^2)$=rank($A$), $A^2A^*=A^*A^2$ and  $A^3A^*=A^*A^3$

I have done one part. That is given $AA^*=A^*A$ , I have solved. How to prove the reverse side

Comment: how did you prove the first direction?

Comment: Then $A$ will be a normal matrix.

Comment: That might even be your definition of normal... so then what?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix

Comment: Add details of what you've done to the opening post maybe?

Comment: One side is obvious...

Comment: Well OK then, what part of the reverse direction isn't obvious? What have you done? Where do you get stuck? Etc.

Comment: Perhaps consider the minimal polynomial of $A$. Note that $A^kA^* = A^*A^k$ for $k=2,3...$.

Comment: Any movement or was this an ask & run?

Comment: I could not solve the problem

Comment: What is special about the minimal polynomial of $A$? It must have one of two particular forms.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

Show that $A^k A^* = A^* A^k$ for $k=2,3,...$.

Show that if $\operatorname{rk} A = \operatorname{rk} A^2$ then the algebraic & geometric multiplicity of any **zero** eigenvalue is the same. Hence the minimal polynomial of $A$ has, at most, a simple zero at zero.

Show that if $A$ is invertible, we can write $A^{-1}$ as a polynomial in $A$ and use that to show that $A^{-1} A^2 A^* = A^* A^2 A^{-1}$.

Show that if $A$ is not invertible then, using $\psi_A$ that we have
$A (A^l+\cdots+ m_1 I) = 0$ for some $m_1 \neq 0$ and so we can write $A$ as a finite sum of multiples of $A^2,A^3,...$. Then the result follows.